# Java LOC counting by comparing two project

Tags: java, eclipse, lines-of-code

I have two `Java` projects in eclipse. Same project but different versions.

Now I want to compare these projects and find out the Inserted, Modified, Deleted `LOC`s of each `java` project.

Is there any plugins are available for this same purpose? Or is there any such tools are available? Please advise me.

Comment: erm, something like: `for i in dir_1/**/*.java; do p='basename $i'; diff $i 'find dir2 -name $p'; done`, route the output to a file and you've got all the diffs... I'd be surprised if eclipse doesn't have a diff plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click to projects/folders/packages in Eclipse, right click and select `Compare With` > `Each Other`. That will give you an overview of the differences between them. It does not give it on a line basis however, nor does it recurse into subdirectories.

On Linux, you could use `diff` and `diffstat` together like follows.

```
diff -rN old-dir new-dir | diffstat
```

Argument `-r` will make the diff recursive (i.e. look in subdirectories), and `-N` will treat missing files as empty (to report lines as added, rather than the file as added).

This will produce a list like:

```
directory/some-file  |    5 +++++
directory/other-file |   18 +++++++++-------
2 files changed, 14 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
```

It doesn't report number of modified files, but inserted and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) can compare a whole hierarchy of files and tell you which exists on one side only, and what are the difference between the left and right versions if a file exists in both hierarchies. Not sure if it counts the number of lines which differ, though.